# Why does setTimeout require code to be enclosed in function?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, the `setTimeout` function requires code to be enclosed in a function.

Examples of invalid timeouts:

- `window.setTimeout(console.log('PING'),3000)`
- `function ping(){console.log('PING')};window.setTimeout(ping(),3000)`

Example of valid timeouts:

- `window.setTimeout(function(){console.log('PING')},3000)`
- `function ping(){console.log('PING')};window.setTimeout(function(){ping()},3000)`

Now my question: why? I understand why normal code might need to be enclosed in a function, but why is it ALWAYS necessary to enclose code in `function(){}`?

Comment: You're free to accept whatever answer you feel that it addresses your concerns. BTW, I feel that you wouldn't ask such question if you would understand the underlying issue: how asynchronous programming work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't always require an *anonymous* function. You can also pass a function reference as the first argument, for example, let's assume you have a function called `log` defined. You can validly write:

```
function log()
{
    console.log( 'PING' );
}

window.setTimeout( log, 200 );
```

Notice that we don't pass the parentheses with the first argument here.

However, you're not able to pass parameters directly to `log()` in this instance, so it's necessary to wrap the function call inside an anonymous function.

Comment: you can pass parameter, using `bind`

Comment: OP can do `window.setTimeout(ping,3000)` for their second timeout of "valid" example as well.

Comment: @BillCriswell Yes, same as `log()` function in the answer.

Comment: @TheReason Indeed, hence why I wrote *pass parameters **directly** to `log()`*.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter! My concern with your answer even when the OP has accepted it is that I don't feel the root issue was what you explain here... The root issue is a misunderstanding of what's asynchronous programming.

Comment: @BenM See the Q&A: **Why does setTimeout require code to be enclosed in function?**. How does your answer addresses this question?

Answer (score 0):

Basically because `setTimeout` is an **asynchronous** operation and you need to give *what to do next* once the timeout is done (i.e. you give a callback function).

Unless JavaScript runtime could block the UI thread and resume execution once the `setTimeout` ends, you need to provide some *executable code* to perform an action once the asynchronous operation has been completed:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
   // Do stuff after 1 second
}, 1000);
```

In the other hand, what would be the point of giving **a `function` return value as argument**? Check this **wrong** code to be more illustrative:

```
// You do some action even BEFORE the timeout operation has been completed?
setTimeout(doStuff(), 1000);
```

### Further reading

- [*Callbacks* in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)#JavaScript)

Comment: lol, we both got downvoted for who know what. It seems like there is some weird way to execute code directly now that I look at the docs, so maybe people are upset we are not mentioning the wrong way to do things.

Comment: Adding parentheses after `doStuff()` in your second snippet is invalid. It will pass the **return** of `doStuff`.

Comment: @BenM Exactly... It's how I show that it would make no sense to do so.

Comment: @BenM I've updated my answer to be more concise about that this snippet is intended to be *wrong*

Answer (score 0):

The code is required to be enclosed in a function because, the setTimeout function does not execute individual lines of code. It takes two, arguments - the first argument is a callback function, and the second argument is the time in milliseconds. The callback function will be called by the setTimeout function internally after the specified amount of time passes.

In the example you gave

```
window.setTimeout(function(){console.log('PING')},3000)
```

you pass an ***anonymous*** function which would be called after 3000 milliseconds or 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be enclosed in `function(){}` but it does need to be a parameter of type `Function`.

In the case of `window.setTimeout(console.log('PING'),3000)`, what would happen is that `console.log()` would immediately be executed and the return value (which is `undefined`) would be passed to the `setTimeout` function.  This code isn't passing a function as a parameter, it's passing the return value of a function as a parameter.  Essentially, it's just a shorter way of writing this:

```
var retVal = console.log('PING');  // retVal === undefined
window.setTimeout(retVal,3000);
```

That's not special to `setTimeout`.  `console.log` without () is a function, but `console.log()` means to invoke that function.

There are other methods to pass a function in to `setTimeout`, but the anonymous function is typically the cleanest.

Technically, this would work, too:

`window.setTimeout(console.log,3000)`

but it would not allow you to specify a parameter, making it rather useless here.  This could be avoided by binding parameters:

`window.setTimeout(console.log.bind(null,'PING'),3000)`

In this case, `bind` is a function which is being invoked (as you can see by the fact it has parameters supplied), so just as before `bind` is immediately executed.  However, `bind` is a function whose return value is itself a function, and it's that returned function that is passed to `setTimeout` and called three seconds later.  This technique (which you will see used with bind, call, and apply) is called **partial application** which really just means that you transform a function taking some parameters into a function taking fewer parameters (in this case, zero parameters) by specifying the parameters now but executing the function later.

Answer (score -1):

Because `setTimeout` is a function that takes two argument - a function, and a number of seconds before that function executes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Parameters:

> func: A function to be executed after the timer expires.
>
> code: An
> optional syntax allows you to include a string instead of a function,
> which is compiled and executed when the timer expires. This syntax is
> not recommended for the same reasons that make using eval() a security
> risk.
>
> delay: Optional The time, in milliseconds (thousandths of a
> second), the timer should wait before the specified function or code
> is executed. If this parameter is omitted, a value of 0 is used. Note
> that the actual delay may be longer; see Reasons for delays longer
> than specified below.
>
> param1, ..., paramN Optional Additional
> parameters which are passed through to the function specified by func
> once the timer expires.

Apparently YOU can just use code, as per the second argument above, but I have never seen it done.

Comment: I'm agree with you that downvoters should justify what they found *wrong* in our answers. In my case, I've not downvoted your answer, but I believe that answering that a language says that you need to pass a callback isn't a deep explanation of why you need either functions or closures to work with `setTimeout`.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Thanks for the reply.